# Need SQL help ranking users by combining data from various tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

users

```
   id  | first_name
 ------+------------
    1 | Ann
    2 | Heidi
    3 | Becky
    4 | Steven
    5 | Jenny
```

service1

```
  id  |     user_id |       fees
------+-------------+-----------
    1 |           3 |    267732
    2 |           1 |     68647
    3 |           2 |     45954
    4 |           1 |     44655
    5 |           5 |     42957
```

service2

```
  id  |     user_id |       fees
------+-------------+-----------
    1 |           3 |      2632
    2 |           1 |         0
    3 |           2 |      4954
    4 |           1 |      4355
    5 |           5 |      2927
```

Here is what my result would be:

```
   first_name  | total_fees
 --------------+------------
    Becky      |     270364
    Ann        |     117657
    Heidi      |      50908
    Jenny      |      45884
    Steven     |          0
```

I am a little new at this, but am having a small issues with creating a query to rank the users with highest total fees.  Here's a my crack of the queries. Basically I want to return the name and fees.

```
SELECT first_name, ((SELECT SUM(fees) FROM service1 WHERE service1.user_id = user.id) + (SELECT SUM(fees) FROM service2 WHERE service2.user_id = user.id)) AS total_fees FROM users ORDER BY total_fees DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  Please tag your questions appropriately.  Also, you should edit your question and show the desired results for the data you have included in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to get the total of the fees for all the users:

```
select u.*, (coalesce(s1.fee, 0) + coalesce(s2.fee, 0)) as total_fee
from users u left join
     (select user_id, sum(fees) as fee
      from service1
      group by user_id
     ) s1
     on u.id = s1.user_id left join
     (select user_id, sum(fees) as fee
      from service2
      group by user_id
     ) s2
     on u.id = s2.user_id;
```

In Postgres, you can use the ANSI standard `RANK()` function to rank these (most databases support this functionality but not MySQL:

```
select u.*, (coalesce(s1.fee, 0) + coalesce(s2.fee, 0)) as total_fee,
       rank() over (order by (coalesce(s1.fee, 0) + coalesce(s2.fee, 0))) as therank
from users u left join
     (select user_id, sum(fees) as fee
      from service1
      group by user_id
     ) s1
     on u.id = s1.user_id left join
     (select user_id, sum(fees) as fee
      from service2
      group by user_id
     ) s2
     on u.id = s2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `left join` on subqueries:

```
SELECT    first_name, COALESCE(sum1, 0) + COALESCE(sum2, 0)
FROM      users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   user_id, SUM(fees) AS sum1
           FROM     service1 s1
           GROUP BY user_id) ON u.id = s1.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   user_id, SUM(fees) AS sum2
           FROM     service1 s2
           GROUP BY user_id) ON u.id = s2.user_id
```